# Data scraping form input snag rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Building a website which datascrapes the UCAS website for universities and courses, we're trying to limit it to only universities from Scotland, but the below code doesn't seem to work. Location in the form is the name of the input id for that segment of the form on the ucas website but as it is now it still displays all universities.

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController
      def home
    require 'mechanize'


mechanize = Mechanize.new

@uninames_array = []

page = mechanize.get('http://search.ucas.com/')

form = page.forms.first
form['Vac'] = '2'
form['AvailableIn'] = '2016'
form['Location'] =  'scotland'
page = form.submit

page.search('li.result h3').each do |h3|
#  puts h3.text.strip

end

while next_page_link = page.at('.pager a[text()=">"]')
  page = mechanize.get(next_page_link['href'])

page.search('li.result h3').each do |h3|
#    puts h3.text.strip
name = h3.text
  @uninames_array.push(name)
  end
end
  end


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that CountryCode variable in the page is initialized in javascript. That's why the request didn't displayed the expected results.

Mechanize can't deal with javascript environment but you can send a search request as a get request in which you have to specified all arguments as the CountryCode.

example:

```
require 'mechanize'
mechanize = Mechanize.new

@uninames_array = []

#page = mechanize.get('http://search.ucas.com/search/providers?CountryCode=&RegionCode=&Lat=&Lng=&Feather=&Vac=2&Query=&ProviderQuery=&AcpId=&Location=scotland&IsFeatherProcessed=True&SubjectCode=&AvailableIn=2016')
page = mechanize.get('http://search.ucas.com/search/providers?CountryCode=3&RegionCode=&Lat=&Lng=&Feather=&Vac=2&Query=&ProviderQuery=&AcpId=&Location=scotland&IsFeatherProcessed=True&SubjectCode=&AvailableIn=2016')


page.search('li.result h3').each do |h3|
  name = h3.text
  @uninames_array.push(name)
end

while next_page_link = page.at('.pager a[text()=">"]')
  page = mechanize.get(next_page_link['href'])

  page.search('li.result h3').each do |h3|
    name = h3.text
    @uninames_array.push(name)
  end
end

puts @uninames_array.to_s
```

If you need to access all countries data there is a javascript in the page which contains them:

```
var countries = [],
regions, geoCordinates;
countries.england = 1;
countries.wales = 2;
countries.scotland = 3;
countries["northern ireland"] = 4;
countries.ni = 4;
countries.ireland = 4;
countries.uk = "1|2|3|4|5";
countries["united kingdom"] = "1|2|3|4|5";
regions = [];
regions["central scotland"] = 301;
regions["channel isles"] = 901;
regions["channel islands"] = 901;
regions["dumfries and galloway"] = 302;
regions["east midlands"] = 101;
regions["east england"] = 102;
regions["east sussex"] = 111;
regions["east wales"] = 201;
regions.fife = 303;
regions.grampian = 304;
regions["isle man"] = 902;
regions.london = 103;
regions.lothian = 305;
regions["mid wales"] = 202;
regions["north east"] = 104;
regions["north east england"] = 104;
regions["north wales"] = 203;
regions["north west"] = 105;
regions["north west england"] = 105;
regions.orkney = 306;
regions["scottish borders"] = 307;
regions["scottish highlands"] = 308;
regions["shetland islands"] = 309;
regions["south east"] = 106;
regions["south east england"] = 106;
regions["south east wales"] = 204;
regions["south wales"] = 205;
regions["south west"] = 107;
regions["south west england"] = 107;
regions.strathclyde = 310;
regions.tayside = 311;
regions["west midlands"] = 108;
regions["west sussex"] = 112;
regions["west wales"] = 206;
regions["yorkshire and humber"] = 109;
regions["yorkshire and the humber"] = 109;
regions.yorkshire = 109;
regions.bedfordshire = 114;
regions.essex = 10201;
regions.kent = 10601;
regions.hampshire = 10602;
regions.cornwall = 10701;
regions["north yorkshire"] = 10901;
regions.midlands = "101|108";
regions.sussex = "111|112";
regions["north england"] = "104|105|109";
regions["northern england"] = "104|105|109";
regions["south england"] = "102|103|106|107|114";
regions["southern england"] = "102|103|106|107|114";
geoCordinates = [];
geoCordinates.jordanstown = "54.68627,-5.88206,0"
```

Comment: We've tried something similar to your suggested example, as well as your example, but they also provide us with a problem. They display only one university - The University of the West of Scotland, not all 21 Scottish institutions.

Comment: Sorry I missed to update @uninames_array on the first page (code edited). There is 21 results as expected.